# Nested Splitter with Notebook and Panel in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to create simple window splitted horizontally. `wx.Notebook` with some tabs on top and simple `wx.Panel` under notebook. I cannot realize how to use `wx.SplitterWindow()` to do it. When I try different methods, notebook occupies all the window and bottom panel is unavailable.

Notice: I want a bottom panel to be viewable always. Not just for one notebook tab like in usual examples.

Or maybe splitted window is not a right way to achieve my needs?

[image: window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [wx.BoxSizer](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.BoxSizer.html) with `orient = VERTICAL`

Add first the notebook and then the bottom panel.

You must tell which of these two items gets resized when the main window is resized. It can be any combination you like: all to the notebok, all to the panel, or in the proportion you wish.

See [sizer doc](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/sizers_overview.html#sizers-overview) or google any wxsizer tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with sizers, of course, as indicated in the answer by Ripi2, but you can also do it with `wxSplitterWindow`. The thing to keep in mind with it is that the controls that you want to put in it must use the splitter itself as parent. I.e. you need to create the splitter first, then the notebook with it as a parent, then the panel with the splitter as parent too, and then call `SplitHorizontally(notebook, panel)`.